# How to performance test workflow execution?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, gatling

I have 2 APIs

- Create a workflow (http POST request)
- Check workflow status (http GET
  request)

I want to performance test on how much time does workflow takes to complete.

Tried two ways:

**Option 1** Created a java test that triggers workflow create API and then poll status API to check if status turns to CREATED. I check the time taken in this process which gives me performance results.

**Option 2** Was using Gatling to do the same

```
val createWorkflow = http("create").post("").body(ElFileBody("src/main/resources/weather.json")).asJson.check(status.is(200))
    .check(jsonPath("$.id").saveAs("id"))

  val statusWorkflow = http("status").get("/${id}")
    .check(jsonPath("$.status").saveAs("status")).asJson.check(status.is(200))


  val scn = scenario("CREATING")
    .exec(createWorkflow)
    .repeat(20){exec(statusWorkflow)}
```

Gatling one didn't really work (or I am doing it in some wrong way). Is there a way in Gatling I can merge multiple requests and do something similar to Option 1

Is there some other tool that can help me out to performance test such scenarios?

Comment: It sounds like you could utilize Gatling's tryMax feature which allows trying a block N times:
https://gatling.io/docs/current/advanced_tutorial/#step-05-check-and-failure-management

Answer (score 0):

I think something like below should work when using Gatling's tryMax

```
.tryMax(100) {
  pause(1)
  .exec(http("status").get("/${id}")
    .check(jsonPath("$.status").saveAs("status")).asJson.check(status.is(200))
  )
}
```

Note: I didn't try this out locally. More information about tryMax:
https://medium.com/@vcomposieux/load-testing-gatling-tips-tricks-47e829e5d449 (Polling: waiting for an asynchronous task)

https://gatling.io/docs/current/advanced_tutorial/#step-05-check-and-failure-management

Comment: Thanks on this one. So below solves things upto some extend
`val scn = scenario("CREATING")
  .exec(createWorkflow)
  .doIf("${id.exists()}") {
    tryMax(100) {
      exec(statusWorkflow1.check(jsonPath("$.status").is("CREATED")))
    }
  }`
But this doesn’t solve what I wanted. This gives result something like 

Create OK 1 time of API responses
status OK 1 KO 16 time of API responses

I want the time taken for workflow from CREATION to COMPLETED, not the API response time.